# Closing the gap between convergence and divergence of $\sum_n 1/n^{1 + 1/f(n)}$ for increasing $f$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have managed to show that $\sum_n 1/n^{1 + 1 / \log n}$ diverges and $\sum_n 1/n^{1 + 1 / \log \log n}$ converges. But the growth rates of $\log n$ and $\log \log n$ are very different. Can someone close the gap, i.e. come up with two increasing functions $f,g$ that have much more similar growth rates, such that $\sum_n 1/n^{1 + 1/f(n)}$ diverges and $\sum_n 1/n^{1 + 1/g(n)}$ converges?

As an analog/motivation of what I'm looking for, $\sum_n 1/n \log n$ diverges while $\sum_n 1/n (\log n)^{1 + \epsilon}$ converges for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Any pointers as to how you did said proofs? Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Cauchy's condensation argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we know that:
$$D_k=\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n\log n\log \log n\ldots \log^{(k)}n}$$
diverges (we take $N$ big enough to make the denominator positive) while
$$C_k=\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n\log n\log \log n\ldots \left(\log^{(k)}n\right)^2}$$
converges. This gives a pretty tight gap (depending on $k$).

Comment: This is a nice observation and I'm familiar with the result. I'm wondering how to translate it to $1/n^{1 + 1/f(n)}$ but I think I know how so my question is a bit trivial. I'll post as an answer.

Comment: $ n\cdot g(n) = \exp(\log n +\log g(n))$ hence just take $$f(n)=\frac{\log n}{\log g(n)}=\frac{\log n}{\log\log n+\log\log\log n+\ldots}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If we have $\sum_n 1/nF(n)$ diverges and $\sum_n 1/nG(n)$ converges, then we can rewrite the first series e.g. as

$$\sum_n 1/n e^{\log F(n)} = \sum_n 1/n^{1 + (\log F(n))/\log n}$$

so we can put $f(n) = \log n /\log F(n)$ and similarly obtain $g(n) = \log n / \log G(n) $. So provided these functions are increasing, we can choose $F$ and $G$ to have arbitrarily close growth rates (as pointed out in another answer) and we are done.